# how to develop a program for finding the location of an object in cctv camera range?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can anyone suggest me that,is it possible to develop a program in vb.net or C# which can find the location of vehicle in a cctv camera range?if possible ,what are the APIs and technologies used for it?can any one suggest any link or the steps involved in this process...?

Comment: Is kind of assignment you got?

Comment: It need lots of alogrithm and programs. You can refer IEEE projects and on code.google.com

Comment: yea...it is an assignment i got.